# How to create a service in ubuntu then access to it by url?

Tags: php

I am reading about how to create a sevice like:

The first link I read is.
https://geekytheory.com/crear-un-servicio-en-linux

But when I type following line in prompt

```
$ sudo service nameservice start
Failed to start nameservice.service: Unit nameservice.service not found
```

I create this script

```
/var/www/myproject/myscript.php
```

I checked all the permissions

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1069 feb 2 15:49 nameservice 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 feb 2 15:56 myscript.php
```

`/var/www/myproject/myscript.php` has this content

```
<?php
    echo "OK";
?>
```

Could you help me? This is the first manual script I wrote.

My intention is to add this service and then call the url `http://localhost/getanswer` to show it to me in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the guide you linked here does something different than what you want to do. In order to run php, you need apache and php installed and configured, have a look here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

then you can start apache by running

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

(maybe you need top run php too)
then open the browser and go to

http://localhost/myproject/myscript.php

to see your php running

Comment: Well I think I have this working.

I open the browser and go to

http://localhost/myproject/myscript.php

and I have answer expected like: [browser][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReX3d.png


    <?php
       echo "OK";
    ?>

Then I need how to connect with post request of this url to show one answer or other.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I have this working.

I open the browser and go to

http://localhost/myproject/myscript.php

and I have answer expected like: [browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReX3d.png)

```
<?php
   echo "OK";
?>
```

Then I need how to connect with post request of this url to show one answer or other.